# wrong datatype due to #define macro in dll

Tags: c, matlab, matlab-deployment

Matlab Warning:

```
The data type 'double#' used by structure  does not exist. The structure may not be usable.
```

It is recognising macro as double# which is declared as double.

Comment: You should probably include the code causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should include the code.

My guess would be that the code is not properly pre-processed.

No idea why you are mixing C and Matlab code though, you need to provide more context.